# Weird outputs while using DataOutputStream

Tags: java, file-io, dataoutputstream

I'm using DataOutputStream of Java IO in order to write to a file but when I execute the program, I don't get the correct output, instead, I get weird characters. -Although I have noticed that only writing strings using the writeUTF(String str) method works, even using writeBytes(String s) produces a weird character that's supposed to be space character- The code part of writing to file is below, any ideas on possible causes, maybe something related to encodings? Thanks in advance.

```
FileOutputStream fs= new FileOutputStream("Path/to/my/file");

DataOutputStream ds = new DataOutputStream(fs);


ds.writeBoolean(false);
ds.writeChar('A');
ds.writeInt(42);
ds.writeBytes("test1");
ds.writeUTF("test2");


fs.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DataOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) class is defined to write a *stream of bytes*, not a *stream of characters*. This stream of bytes has the purpose of being efficiently and portably stored, no matter whether humans can read it or not.

If you want human-readable text files, use an XML writer.

By the way, the output you get *is* correct, it's rather your understanding that is wrong. You probably just need to read and understand the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) that comes with the class.

Answer (score 1):

Data Streams are for binary data  DataOutputStream writing the integer in binary format, i.e. it splits the integer into 4 bytes and writes those